# Apache Mesos Agent with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere

I am working on integrating Mesos with Kafka, as per the git hub documentation scheduler can be run on a independent machine which has mesos and kafka installed and with the help of configuration registration to mesos-master can be done.

How do we run brokers on agents, from scheduler and what configuration is required to run broker on agent?

Comment: The documentation for Mesos Kafka is actually pretty informative - https://github.com/mesos/kafka#scheduler-configuration you need to build the project, download Kafka distribution you wish to launch and place it in the same directory you will launch the scheduler from. Then you may add/start brokers via CLI

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using Docker, you can make use of the Docker image as described in

- https://github.com/mesos/kafka/tree/master/src/docker#intro

You can launch the Kafka Scheduler image with Marathon, and then either use the REST API or CLI to start brokers/topics.

The dispatching of the actual brokers will then be done by the Mesos software itself. Using the brokers is done via the defined Zookeeper node name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was able to run the scheduler through shell and as well as docker.
I had two questions though

```
sudo docker run -t -p 5900:5900 --net=host root/kafka-mesos ./kafka-mesos.sh \ 
  scheduler --master=192.168.1.115:5050 --zk=192.168.1.115:2181 \
  --api=http://192.168.1.118:5900 --storage=zk:/kafka-mesos \
  --log=/var/log/mesos.log --debug=true
```

I have used above command in marathon to run the container, if I remove `--net=host` the schedule registers with docker containers ip with the master but after adding `--net=host` it uses the agent's ip and port forwards it to docker container. Is there any better way?

The second question is how many schedulers can we bring up in the one mesos cluster say 3 master 5 agents i.e. can we scale or support  scheduler cluster?